# To design an algorithm for counting n distinct 2-D points in array

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

```
public class IntersectionOfTwoSets {

public class Point implements Comparable{
    int x;
    int y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        if(this.x > ((Point)o).x) return 1;
        if(this.x < ((Point)o).x) return -1;
        if(this.y > ((Point)o).y) return 1;
        if(this.y < ((Point)o).y) return -1;
        return 0;
    }
}

public Point[] intersectionOf(Point[] a, Point[] b) {
    List<Point> result = new ArrayList<>();
    Arrays.sort(a);
    Arrays.sort(b);

    for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < a.length && j < b.length; ) {
        if(a[i].compareTo(b[j]) == 0) {
            result.add(a[i]);
            i++;
            j++;
        } else if (a[i].compareTo(b[j]) < 0) {
            i ++;
        } else {
            j ++;
        }
    }
    return (Point[])result.toArray();
}
```

Given two arrays a and b, containing n distinct 2D points.Design an algorithm to count the number of points that are contained in both array
(Trouble in understanding the code)
I have multiple questions related to this code:

1. Why are we creating nested class?
2. Why are we incrementing i and j in the else if body rather than icrementing them in for statement?
3. How main method will create objects of two Point array?

(If someone has better solution to this question it is really appreciated.)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You appear to be asking us to do your homework for you.  We will not be doing this, as doing so would not be a benefit to anyone, and in the long term, it will actually be a net harm to you.   Please review your class notes, visit your instructor's office hours, read this [open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems), and [edit] this question to be more specific with where you are having difficulty.

Comment: `"Why are we creating nested class?"` -- the code does not reveal the reasoning behind this, and likely it is driven by the requirements, requirements that we are not fully aware of yet.  `"How is i++ and j++ implemented in intersectionOf method?"` -- what do you mean? What confuses you about the for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use C++ but I can answer your question. The algorithm is ok <del>but you should rephrase your question to reflect that you are having trouble understanding the algorithm</del>.

**1) Why are we creating nested class?**
To avoid type conflict

```
+- IntersectionOfTwoSets (class) ------+
|    |                                 |
|    o- Point (class)                  |
|    |                                 |
|    o- intersectionOf (function)      |
|                                      |
+--------------------------------------+
```

can be implemented without `IntersectionOfTwoSets` but take note that `Point` is a very common name and is perhaps already implemented in any library you intend to add to your project. implementing `Point` in `IntersectionOfTwoSets` makes your implementation unique (a concept known as `namespace` in C++ and use of which is considered good programming practice)

---

> standard ***for loop*** syntax is: *`for`* (*`init`*; *`condition`*; *`increment`*)

Observe that the increment component of the loop is missing instead you find it within the loop

---

**2) *How is i++ and j++ implemented in intersectionOf method?***
`i++` is simply `i += 1`;

here is a simplified version of the code

```
given two sets a & b
sort a & b
initialize empty array (result)
loop (...)
| if (a[i] == b[j])
|  add a[i] to result, then increment i & j
| if (a[i] < b[j])
|  increment i
| if (b[j] < a[i])
|  increment j
| if (i >= a.size()) or (j >= b.size())
|  stop
return result
```

let's test the algorithim on a set of integers

```
let a: [2, 1, 10, 9]
let b: [1, 5, 2, 7, 6]

let result: []

Arrays.sort(a); // a: [1, 2, 9, 10]
Arrays.sort(b); // b: [1, 2, 5, 6, 7]

loop(...)
| 1: add 1 to result, increment i & j
| 2: add 2 to result, increment i & j
| 3: (j == 2) increment only j (5 < 9)
| 4: (j == 3) increment only j (6 < 9)
| 5: (j == 4) increment only j (7 < 9)
| 6: (j == 5) stop because j >= b.size()

return result // [1, 2]
```

it should also work on a set of points

**3) *How main method will create objects of two Point array?***
in C++ the syntax is:

```
IntersectionOfTwoSets::Point a[n], b[n];
or
List<IntersectionOfTwoSets::Point> a, b;
```

but in Java i'm almost sure it is:

```
List<IntersectionOfTwoSets.Point> a, b;
or
IntersectionOfTwoSets::Point a = new IntersectionOfTwoSets::Point[n];
IntersectionOfTwoSets::Point b = new IntersectionOfTwoSets::Point[n];
```